# How can I make a CSV file with what will be in my TextInputs?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm on an app project where I want to put information into TextInputs, validate with a button and that creates me a .CSV file with what was contained in the TextInputs.

I created screens with Builder but I don't know how can I acess the data contained in textinputs and identify each ones where there are more than one input.

I've been told about StringProperty but I don't understand how to use it and implement it to my solution.

```
<CreerSecteurScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            text: 'Nom'
        TextInput:
            text: 'Age'
        TextInput:
            text: 'Lore'
        Button:
            text: 'Créer le Secteur'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'admin_screen'
```

Currently the graphical part works so nicely but that's all. Can't acess the data contained in TextInput. Can't process it and I don't know how to create a CSV from those Inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text from the widgets by using the `.text` attribute. To reference the text inputs, give them all `id`s. Then you can create a python function in your `App` class to handle them. A quick example:

`main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    def print_textinput_values(self, text1, text2):
        print(text1)
        print(text2)

MainApp().run()
```

`main.kv`

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    TextInput:
        id: the_first_input
    TextInput:
        id: the_second_input
    Button:
        text: "Print text"
        on_release:
            app.print_textinput_values(the_first_input.text, the_second_input.text)
```

the `app` keyword in the `kv` code refers to your `App` class (`MainApp` in this example), and you can use it to call any functions you define.

`id` is something you can specify for any Kivy widget, whether it's a `TextInput`, `Label`, `Button` or anything else. Very useful.

Since I've named my `App` class `MainApp`, it will automatically try to load a file named `main.kv`, so that's how the interface is made.